# How to stream iOS video over bluetooth to another device?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, bluetooth, video-streaming

For a video-based game I want to stream the video of one device to another. Is there a way to do this with bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stream any data you like across bluetooth. However, you might be limited by the bandwidth available on a bluetooth connection.